# Cocoa way of doing applications with delegates

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, coding-style

i have a method, in which i want to accomplish a given task, however, the asynchronous commands and delegates made it difficult

i can do this :

```
- (void) fooPart1 
{
    ...
    SomeAssynchronousMethos * assync = [[SomeAssynchronousMethos alloc] init];
    assync.delegate = self;
    [assync start];

}

- (void) fooPart2
{
   ...
   possibly some other assync
}

- (void)someAssynchronousMethosDelegateDidiFinish
{
    [self fooPart2];
}
```

But isn't there a way to do smith. like this

```
- (void) foo
{
    ...
    SomeAssynchronousMethos * assync = [[SomeAssynchronousMethos alloc] init];
    assync.delegate = self;
    [assync start];

    wait for signal, but class is not blocked
    ...
    possibly some other assync

}

- (void)someAssynchronousMethosDelegateDidiFinish
{
    continue in foo after [assync start]
}
```

I don't like the idea of splitting a function to 2 or more parts, but is this the way how it is done in cocoa? or is there a better practice?

**why i dont like this concept and searching for a better way of doing it :**

- lets say, i want to use a variable only for compleating a task - if i have everything in one function, i just use it, and than the var dies as i leave the function, if its split, i have to keep the var somehow around, until it doesnt finish
- the code becomes fragmented and more difficult to read and maintain
- may lead to bug
- i end up with a set of part function, that needs to be called in precise order to accomplish one task (for which one function would be more suitable)

i used to make a thread and do only synchronous calls there, but not everything supports a synchronous call

what would be realy nice, is to have smth, like

```
- (void) foo
{
    ...
    int smth = 5;
    SomeAssynchronousMethos * assync = [[SomeAssynchronousMethos alloc] init];
    assync.delegate = self;
    @freez([assync start]);
    // when freez - the local function variables are frozen 
    // (next commands in function are not excuted until unfreez)
    // from outer look, it looks like the function finished      
    // however when unfreeze, it is called from this point on

    //int smth is still 5
}

- (void)someAssynchronousMethosDelegateDidiFinish
{
    @unfreez([assync start]);
}
```

when the execution would reach freez, it would store all local vars allocated in function and when called unfreez, it would continue from that point on, when it was freez with that command

Comment: I'm confused.  Starting a true async task shouldn't block, so it should be possible to do it in one method.  With that said, methods should accomplish one single thing, so the first is better written code.

Comment: yes, the problem is when starting a true async task, that the function continues, however i want that true async task starts, however, when it is finished, it continues from the spot it was called (like a synchronous call), so my function is not split into x part

Comment: The whole point of an async task is to continue execution. Splitting your code into different methods/blocks to be called before and after the task completion is a GOOD thing, not a bad thing.  Perhaps if you post more code we can see why splitting your method is so undesirable.

Comment: well i want my function to perform a one compleate task, not this task to be shuttered accross multiple part functions (part functions which dont work when not executed in precise order - i dont know, but i thing its a bad concept)... moreover if i want to use a variable from function part1, i have to keep it around (globaly), until part2 of the function comes to play

Comment: There's lots of ways to ensure that tasks are completed in the right order, even asynchronous ones.  You certainly don't have to keep variables around globally.  Use objects and the encapsulation they provide.  Without more specifics it's hard for anyone to help, but I strongly suspect your insistence is based more around a lack of ideas, rather than it being the best design.  With more details, people can suggest more optimal design patterns.  Note JeremyP's answer below for instance.  There's no difference between picking up execution where it left off and calling a completion handler block.

Answer (score 4):

This seems like an ideal application of a completion handler [block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxUsing.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH5-SW2).

Alter your `start` method to take a parameter which is a block and call it like so:

```
- (void) fooPart1 
{
    ...
    SomeAssynchronousMethos * assync = [[SomeAssynchronousMethos alloc] init];
    [assync startOnComplete: ^(NSError* error) // example, you can have any params or none
        {
            // handle error if not nil
            if (error != nil)
            {
                // do something with it
            }
            // code to do on completion
        }]; 
}
```

Your start method would look something like this

```
-(void) startOnComplete: (void(^)(NSError*)) completionBlock
{
    // copy the block somewhere
    theSavedCompletionBlock = [completionBlock copy];
    // kick off async operation
}

-(void) someMethodThatRunsAttheEndOfTheAsyncOp
{
    theSavedCompletionBlock(nilOrError);
    [theSavedCompletionBlock release];
}
```

Comment: +1 It's quite easy to adapt existing classes to use blocks instead of callbacks. Have a look on GitHub. (This is for the Original questioner, not for you Jeremy).